# How incorporate On Duplicate Key with bind_param

Tags: php, mysql

Hi How can i incorporate `On Duplicate Key` with `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO assy (ItemID,partid,qty,rev,bomEntry) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 'A',?)  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE partid=$bom");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssii", $itemid, $bom, $qty, $bomEntry) or die(mysqli_error($con));

    $recordd = $tv->search(454545400000, 's=2'); 
    //print_r($recordd);echo"1<br/>";
    foreach($recordd as $data2) { 
        $itemid = $data2['fields']['CALC STOCK NO']; 

        $bomEntry = 1;
        if ($data2['fields']['BOM WHEEL PN']) {
            $bom = $data2['fields']['BOM WHEEL PN']; 
            $qty=1;
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
            $bomEntry++;
        }

    }
```

I tried something like

```
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO table_name  (ItemID,partid,qty,rev,bomEntry) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 'A',?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE patid=$bom;");
   .
   .
   .
```

but it set to blank

Comment: @chris85 i think  i did, which variable values?

Comment: I did here `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssii", $itemid, $bom, $qty, $bomEntry) or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: @chris85 added the rest of if statement they all similar to the `if` statement on the original Questions

Comment: @chris85 updated that

Comment: that's how it looks like in the question right?

Comment: No, `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE partid=$bom`.

Comment: I used these two code for the bind and for the query i dont know what to change  `$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO assy (ItemID,partid,qty,rev,bomEntry) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 'A',?)  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE partid=$bom");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssii", $itemid, $bom, $qty, $bomEntry)`

Comment: oooh Thank you @chris85  that works great!

Comment: Okay, I'll post that as an answer and a write up.

Comment: sure i will thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$bom` is a string so it need to be quoted, or preferably swapped out of the query and bound via a placeholder. Here is the placeholder and binding approach:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO assy (ItemID,partid,qty,rev,bomEntry) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 'A',?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE partid=?"); 
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssiis", $itemid, $bom, $qty, $bomEntry, $bom);
```

With prepared statements you rarely will want variables in your query.